# Can I replace a standard outlet that's protected with an upstream GFCI to prevent nuisance trips?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, gfci

I have a GFI outlet in one bathroom controlling a non-GFI outlet in another bathroom. Can I replace the non-GFI with a GFI and will that stop the non-GFI from shutting down or do I need to have and electrician install another breaker for the new GFI?

Comment: Yes you can replace the non-GFI with a GFI, but it's unlikely to help much (if at all). Unless you figure out why the 1st GFI is tripping you'll probably be wasting your time.

Comment: Please explain the problem better. If the problem is that the standard outlet is going out when the GFCI  trips, then no, your idea won't help.

Comment: Also, bathroom outlets are *required* to be GFCI protected. It's a matter of life and death.

Comment: The GFI is over 10 years old, could there be a problem with that needing to be replaced?

Comment: What kind of load is on the GFCI that is being tripped? What all is piggy backed from it or is it just by itself to the breaker box? How many Amps is the GFCI rated for?

Comment: How often is the GFCI tripping and is there a pattern to it?  Is someone using either outlet when it trips?  Is this is an old two-wire circuit or a modern one with a ground (green or bare) wire?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd remove the GFCI from the circuit (nut the wires together and make it separate, as in don't use the LOAD screws) and then put a separate GFCI in the other bathroom in the same way. It's expensive (and unnecessary) but you avoid having a bathroom outlet inexplicably going dead (trip the GFCI bathroom outlet directly and your normal outlet goes out). This way, each GFCI can trip independently of the other.

As to nuisance trips, assuming you have no wiring issues, the GFCI might be going bad. Replacing it isn't a bad idea.